# call a function for n times with 2 second delay

Tags: javascript

Im running a code where I must create a function and call it for 3 times with 2 seconds delay between each.I am having trouble calling it more than once. how can i solve this?I use javascript. i create myfunc() to log hello in console every 2 seconds for 3 times.

Comment: Hi, please share the code you already have so we can take a look.

Comment: Please add your code as a [mre], in accordance with [ask] - we can't help you very much otherwise.

Comment: `setInterval` is used if you want to call a function on a schedule. It's unclear what you've tried or what the issue is. A vague description is no substitute for simply showing the code

Comment: I think `setTimeout` would be more suitable as it would fire finite number of times.

Comment: Closing questions isn't really helping people who are asking for help. The most simple way to achieve what you are looking for is to call once and schedule the 2 other calls: `myfunc(); setTimeout(myfunc, 2000); setTimeout(myfunc, 4000);`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myFunc = () => console.log("hello");

const runFunc = async (func, times, delay) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    func();
    if (i + 1 < times) await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, delay));
  }
}

runFunc(myFunc, 3, 2 * 1000);
```

or this

```js
const myFunc = () => console.log("hello");

const runFunc = async (func, times, delay) => {
  if (times >= 1) func();
  times--;
  if (times >= 1) {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      times--;
      if (times <= 0) clearInterval(interval);
      func();
    }, delay);
  }
}

runFunc(myFunc, 3, 2 * 1000);
```

Comment: Neat...but why do all that instead of simply using setInterval? Your answer should contain an explanation as well as just a code dump.

Comment: setInterval requires a lot of extra stuff since it doesn't run immediately. If you want to have an interval run every hour, it would take an hour for the first time to start

Comment: That requires you to just  run it once and then set the interval. One line extra. I wouldn't calls that "a lot"...but OK.

Comment: @ADyson It's a lot when you need to take into account the amount of `times`